# Hash table using linear probing

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, hash-map

This code is meant to implement a hash table class which uses linear probing.

I'm doing this to improve my style and to improve my knowledge of fundamental algorithms/data structures for an upcoming coding interview.

```
class Hash:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 11
        self.vals = [None] * self.size
        self.keys = [None] * self.size
        self.step = 1

    def put(self, key, val):
        ind = self.hash(key)

        if self.keys[ind] == None:
            self.keys[ind] = key
            self.vals[ind] = val

        elif self.keys[ind] == key:
            self.vals[ind] = val

        else:
            ind = self.rehash(ind)

            while (self.keys[ind] != None and 
                   self.keys[ind] != key):
                ind = self.rehash(ind)

            if self.keys[ind] == None:
                self.keys[ind] = key
                self.vals[ind] = val

            elif self.keys[ind] == key:
                self.vals[ind] = val

    def get(self, key):
        ind = self.hash(key)
        start_ind = ind
        val = None
        done = False

        while not done:
            if self.keys[ind] == key:
                val = self.vals[ind]
                done = True

            else:
                ind = self.rehash(ind)

                if ind == start_ind:
                    done = True

                elif self.keys[ind] == None:
                    done = True

        return val

    def hash(self, key):
        return key % self.size

    def rehash(self, oldhash):
        return (oldhash + self.step) % self.size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.put(key, val)
```

Answer (score 2):

## `break` (or better yet `return`)

Instead of doing `done = False/True`. You could just use `break` and get rid of `done` altogether. But even better than that, just `return`.

This:

```
        if self.keys[ind] == key:
            val = self.vals[ind]
            done = True
```

Becomes:

```
        if self.keys[ind] == key:
            return self.vals[ind] # Value found!
```

This:

```
            if ind == start_ind:
                done = True

            elif self.keys[ind] == None:
                done = True
```

Becomes:

```
            if ind == start_ind: # Not found!
                return

            elif self.keys[ind] == None: # Not found!
                return
```

(You can `return None` if you want).

This gets rid of the `val` variable (and `done`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Does that mean that instead of `while not done:` I would use `while True:`?

Comment: @cycloidistic: Yes.